# Probability of three events occuring but not both

Tags: statistics

I know the formula: `(A+B)-2*(A*B)` 
but how can I figure this out with three events? 
Would either `(A+B+C)-2*(A*B*C)` or `(A+B+C)-3*(A*B*C)` be correct? 
Or maybe just `(A+B+C)-(A*B*C)`? 
EDIT: I want to find the probability of either A or B or C occuring, but not either of them occuring with each other

Comment: Generally, "both" only applies to _two_ events.  With three, you could have none of the events occur, one of the events occur, two of the events occur, or three of the events occur.  Specify what you're looking for.  Are you wanting to look for the probability exactly one event occurs out of three independent events?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you clarify the meaning of the symbols using standard probability language?

Comment: I would draw and Venn diagram so you can work it out